# How to prevent freeze in Need For Speed Underground?

Tags: need-for-speed-underground

Right before the race starts, the game freezes on the loading screen. I was unable ever to race. My video drivers are the latest as far as I can tell. I read that using older drivers might help get it running, but since that wasn't guaranteed, I didn't do that. I also tried changing resolution and picture quality to no avail. I'd rather not try anything else that won't definitively fix this as when it freezes it's difficult to shutdown even, prompting me to do a hard reset.

Comment: What are your OS and hardware specs?

Answer (score 3):

If you're running in Windows 7 or 8, perhaps try running the game in compatability mode?

- `Right-Click` the shortcut to the game, and select `Properties`
- Under the `Compatibility` tab, select `Run this program in compatibility mode for:` and leave the dropdown as `Windows XP (Service Pack 3)`
- Click `OK` and try running the game again.